# How to register custom filter in micronaut?

Tags: filter, micronaut

I am trying to register custom filter in `micronaut`, but I don't find any `FilterRegistrationBean` kind of classes we have in Spring to register our own filter. I went through the `micronaut` documentation, but not much help for custom filter.

https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#filters

Any pointers please?

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to register custom filter in micronaut, but I don't find
>   any FilterRegistrationBean kind of classes we have in Spring to
>   register our own filter.

They don't really need to be registered, at least not in the way you would with Spring.  If the filter is marked with `@Filter` and is on the `CLASSPATH`, it will be registered.  One of the examples in the docs you linked looks like this:

```
import io.micronaut.http.*;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Filter;
import io.micronaut.http.filter.*;
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;

@Filter("/hello/**") 
public class TraceFilter implements HttpServerFilter { 
    private final TraceService traceService;

    public TraceFilter(TraceService traceService) { 
        this.traceService = traceService;
    }

    ​@Override
   ​public Publisher<MutableHttpResponse<?>> doFilter(HttpRequest<?> request, ServerFilterChain chain) {
       ​return traceService.trace(request)￼
                          ​.switchMap(aBoolean -> chain.proceed(request))￼
                          ​.doOnNext(res ->￼
                               ​res.getHeaders().add("X-Trace-Enabled", "true")
                          ​);
   }
}
```

No additional step is required to put that in play.

I hope that helps.